# Python : Slice each sentence in list of sentences

Tags: python, text-analysis

I am trying to slice each sentence in a list of sentences from [0:10] character of it.

Example of list of sentences: **list name = sd_list**

['I was born and brought up in Delhi.',

'I am using Dell Latitude E5140 laptop since 2012.',

'I work for ABC company since 2014.']

I tried to slice the first 10 characters of each sentence by running the below code and failed.

```
sent10 = [s[0:10] for s in sd_list]
```

By running this I encountered below TypeError

---

TypeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 [s[0:10] for s in sd_list]

in (.0)
----> 1 [s[0:10] for s in sd_list]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

---

--> I even tried defining a function :

```
def sent_slice(text):

     for s in range(0,len(text)):

        text[s] = text[s][0:10]

     return text

sent_slice(sd_list)
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 sent_slice(sd_list)

in sent_slice(text)
      1 def sent_slice(text):
      2     for s in range(0,len(text)):
----> 3         text[s] = text[s][0:10]
      4     return text

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

---

Could someone help me understand this "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" . How can I achieve my goal of slicing sentence?

Comment: Can you show us exactly what is in sd_list?

Comment: Your first attempt is correct. Can you print and see what is stored in sd_list variable?

Comment: There is something more to this. Pls post the full, exact code.

Comment: sd_list contains some 1 lakh+ elements. There were some blank rows which caused the issue. Able to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that you have a `float` in `sd_list`. you can find it by doing something like:

```
print([f for f in sd_list if isinstance(f, float)])
```

Comment: It worked and able to sort out the blank/nan records in the list which caused the issue. Thank You